# GSON should ignore parameterised type if not used by serialized fields?

Tags: java, json, gson

If I have:

```
class X<T> {
   String a;
   T b;
}
```

Then rightly I would expect GSON to complain about the parameterization because it can't serialize field b. However if I change it to:

```
class X<T> {
   String a;
   transient T b;
}
```

GSON should now not care since it shouldn't be serializing the field that uses the type parameter.

Does anyone see any problems with this? I am guessing this is simply an oversight on the part of the GSON developers which I am willing to modify the code to address but I would like to know if that is the case before attempting to do so.

Comment: Is your goal to exclude that field from json serialization? If so, Gson has specific mechanisms: esclusions or annotations.

Comment: [By default](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects), Gson *does* exclude `transient` fields. How do you configure your Gson instance, any custom exclusion setup?

Comment: Also, at least in this trivial case, Gson will happily serialize the class with non-transient `b` a well based on the runtime type. Deserialization is a different matter, though.

Comment: Gson may well be excluding the field but that doesn't mean it isn't checking for a condition that logically doesn't apply. This seems to be the case.

Comment: trapo - the field is excluded if marked transient. The point is GSON is still complaining that it could not serialize that field - which it couldn't if it was trying to do so. However since it's not supposed to be it shouldn't be complaining about something it's not going to do.